# Data transfer from MVC Controller to View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

What is the best way I can get the below data from my controller to a table in my view.

**CONTROLLER**

```
     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult PBHEP(string PC,string FC)
     {
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Conditions> PC_rows = ser.Deserialize<List<Conditions>>(PC);
        List<Conditions> FC_rows = ser.Deserialize<List<Conditions>>(FC);


        PlotXYContext plotXYContext = new PlotXYContext();
        int Township = PC_rows[0].Township, Range = PC_rows[0].Range, Section =  PC_rows[0].Section, Acres = PC_rows[0].Acres, Crop = Convert.ToInt32(PC_rows[0].Crop);

        var query_XYCells = from TRS2Cell in plotXYContext.XYCells
                            where (TRS2Cell.Twnshp == Township) && (TRS2Cell.Rng == Range) && (TRS2Cell.Section == Section)
                            select new { TRS2Cell.Xcell, TRS2Cell.Ycell };
        var output_XYCells = query_XYCells.ToList();

        int XCell = Convert.ToInt32(output_XYCells[0].Xcell), YCell = Convert.ToInt32(output_XYCells[0].Ycell);
        var query_CIRvalues = from aAvgCIR in plotXYContext.CIRvalues
                              where (aAvgCIR.X == XCell) && (aAvgCIR.Y == YCell) && (aAvgCIR.Crop == Crop)
                              select new { aAvgCIR.PumpNetIrrig, aAvgCIR.NonPumpNetIrrig, aAvgCIR.PumpDeepPerc, aAvgCIR.NonPumpDeepPerc };
        var output_CIRvalues = query_CIRvalues.ToList();

        float CIR = output_CIRvalues[0].PumpNetIrrig + output_CIRvalues[0].NonPumpNetIrrig,
            Recharge = output_CIRvalues[0].PumpDeepPerc + output_CIRvalues[0].NonPumpDeepPerc,
            GW_Withdrawal = (CIR - Recharge) * (Acres / 12);

        ViewBag.CIR = CIR;
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult PBHEP()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style =" text-align:center" colspan="10"><b>Computed CIR Offsets</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style =" text-align:center"><b>Township</b></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center"><b>Range</b></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center"><b>Section</b></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center"><b>Crop</b></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center"><b>Acres</b></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center"><b>CIR(IN)</b></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center"><b>Recharge(IN)</b></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center"><b>GW Withdrawal(AF)</b></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center"><b>Platte River Depletion (Percent)</b></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center"><b>Estimated Net Depletion (AF)</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style =" text-align:center" colspan="10"><b>Present Conditions</b></td>
        </tr>
        @(ViewBag.CIR > 0)
        {
         <tr>
            <td style =" text-align:center"><b></b></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center"><b></b></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center"><b></b></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center"><b></b></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center"><b></b></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center"><b></b></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center"><b></b></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center"><b></b></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center"><b></b></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center"><b></b></td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

I have the above table in my VIEW and want the next row populated with the float values in the controller how do I get them there.What is the best practice?

I tried to use ViewBag to update one value but wasnt able to update my UI

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use a View Model or the `ViewBag`.

Comment: How Do I achieve that can you please forward me any links.I tried using viewbag but wasnt able to update the UI.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a strongly typed view with a model of a custom class, for example, take the following controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult TaskView()
    {
        Task t = new Task() { Id = "1", Description= "Task 1", Name="Some Task Name"};

        return View(t);
    }
}

public class Task
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string  Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then your view could look like this:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Controllers.Task

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TaskView";
}

<h2>TaskView</h2>
@Model.Id - @Model.Name - <b>@Model.Description</b>
```

Notice how I used `@model` at the beginning of the page to define the data type and `@Model` later in the page to access the data returned to the view.

Comment: I did create a class for the output parameters but when I debug the .cshtml does show that on post it gives the values but does not show the row being added.

Comment: Remove the check for viewbag.cir if you changed it to use a strongly typed model.

Comment: I actually replaced it with if(IsPost).Is that right?Since I did not want to add that row unless its a post.

Comment: Also when I checked after the post when I return the View,it shows the Layout but after the @RenderBody() the row does not add up.